# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. Updating state of a functional component inside the render method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

Every time I display the cart items I want to update the total price and count of the items using the useState function inside the render method. But, immediately after the UI is rendered I get a react error mentioned above.

*Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve without getting the error?*

```
const Cart = () => {
  const cartItems = useItems()
  const firebase = useFirebase()
  //Items count

  //Total amount of the items
  let [total, updateTotal] = useState(0)
  let [count, updateCount] = useState(1)

  //Method to add items to the cart
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!firebase) return
  }, [firebase, cartItems])




  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Cart" />
      <Navbar count={count} />
      <MDBContainer>
        <MDBCol lg="12" className="">
          <MDBTable responsive className="mt-5 z-depth-1">
            <MDBTableHead>
              <tr className="bg-light">
                <th>
                  <div className="p-1 px-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                    Product
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <div className="p-1 px-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                    Price
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <div className="p-1 px-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                    Quantity
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <div className="p-1 px-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                    Remove
                  </div>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </MDBTableHead>
            <MDBTableBody id="products-list">
              {cartItems.map(product => {
                updateTotal((total += product.price))
                updateCount((count += 1))
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td class="px-3 font-weight-normal">
                      {product.name} <span class="d-none">{product.id}</span>{" "}
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%" class="text-center font-weight-normal">
                      {product.price}
                      <span>/kg </span>{" "}
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%" class="text-center font-weight-normal">
                      {product.count}
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%" class="text-center">
                      <div class="px-3 font-weight-normal">
                        {" "}
                        <button
                          class="bg-transparent border-0"
                          id="delete-button"
                        >
                          <i class="fa fa-trash-alt delete-icon"></i>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                )
              })}
            </MDBTableBody>
            <MDBTableFoot>
              <tr>
                <td className="px-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Total</td>
                <td className="font-weight-bold px-5">&#8377;{total}</td>
                <td className="font-weight-bold pr-2 text-center">{count}</td>
              </tr>
            </MDBTableFoot>
          </MDBTable>
        </MDBCol>
      </MDBContainer>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: Dear @KaranSiddannavar, Please edit your post title if it is possible. short titles are more readable for other users. I think it is better. Maybe you can migrate some concepts of your question inside the post, not its title. thanks a lot, dude. have a good time.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if (!firebase) return
  }, [firebase, cartItems]) This hooks will be called each time firebase or cartItems are changing.  Change [firebase, cartItems] to []

Comment: I want to keep a track of carItems. And if I remove it I don't get any data from the firebase storage.

Comment: Hey guys! I converted [firebase, cartItems] to [], yet I get the same error for using useState inside return method. When I remove the useState function then everything works fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KaranSiddannavar What are you doing in your effect?

Comment: I just see if the firsbase instance is initialized.

Comment: Hey, by seeing the code snippet above, it is difficult to say, what is causing the rerun of useEffect to callback.  One of the dependencies is surely changing on every re-render which is causing infinite runs.

I use this library to debug these kind of cases.
https://github.com/simbathesailor/use-what-changed
 Thanks

Comment: @simbathesailor Can you atleast tell me how can I update my state? After looking at my code you can see what I'm trying to achieve. And I will install your package and debug hooks.

Comment: Can you just add the cartItems response that you will you get and also useItems code. I should be able to help you out

Comment: Can I contact you personally on a channel or something? Or shall I do it over here. Then I can post the solution over here. @simbathesailor

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206191/discuss . You can join this and discuss the problem

Comment: I've messaged you there. Please reply!

Answer (score 3):

use blank `[]` instead of `[firebase, cartItems]`

Comment: I did it! Yet, I get the same error for using state inside the return method

Answer (score 3):

The below code should work for you:

```
const cartItems = useItems();
// I assume this gives you cartItems.

let [total, updateTotal] = useState(() => {
  if (cartItems) {
    // item object {id: "2", name: "Cucumber", category: "vegetable", price: 50, // //count: 0}
    return cartItems.reduce((acc, elem) => {
      acc += elem.price * elem.count;
      return acc;
    }, 0);
  }
  return 0;
});
let [count, updateCount] = useState(cartItems.length);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (cartItems) {
    updateCount(cartItems.length);
    // item object {id: "2", name: "Cucumber", category: "vegetable", price: 50, // //count: 0}
    const total = cartItems.reduce((acc, elem) => {
      acc += elem.price * elem.count;
      return acc;
    }, 0);
    updateTotal(total);
  }
}, [cartItems]);
```

So, basically you need to initiate the state once you get some value from the useItems and then also need to update it when cartItems reference changes

Comment: Can you reply in our chat? I wanted some help.

Answer (score 0):

Putting [firebase, cartItems]  tells react to always re-render if any change is made to these two parametres. So that is why there are too many re-renders.

Comment: I never got an error for doing that! I'm getting an error for using useState() inside return method